# Why is my Pillow app not working with Django

Tags: python, django, python-imaging-library

I followed [this YouTube video](https://youtu.be/KQJRwWpP8hs)  from 15:21 onwards and tried to include `ImageField` to my models in models.py of the model `Topic`. When I tried to migrate the model. It is not working. It says that I need to install pillow (which I did and when I tried again it is still not working. Please refer to this video [The video thats shows how this doesn't work](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1g-mG3IkhqcdkYy0tW_3qKAoT5Q3bKGPU/view?usp=sharing)

Models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
# Create your models here.
class Topic(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'backgroud_images', null = True, blank = True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.text

class Entry(models.Model):
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic,on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    text = models.TextField()
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Entries"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text[:50]
```

the `INSTALLED_APPS` list from settings.py.Is it because I didn't include pillows in here?

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'learning_logs',
    'users',
    'bootstrap4',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Do I do it like this?

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'learning_logs',
    'users',
    'bootstrap4',
    ‘Pillow’,
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    ]
```